# Visual studio not allowing ommision of default parameters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am using VS2010 on a C++ project using opencv.  Many of the calls in opencv have default parameters for the last few parameters to functions.  However, when omitting these parameters in function calls, Visual Studio complains and says `"functionname: too few arguments for call`

Is this a quirk of visual studio?  Is it a setting somewhere that I can turn off?  Why is this occurring.  The code compiles fine under g++.

**edit**

As an example,

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>

int main()
{

    CvMat *rotation_vector = cvCreateMat(3,3, CV_64FC1);
    double rotation[] = { 0, 1, 0,
                -1, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 1 };

    cvInitMatHeader(rotation_vector, 3, 3, CV_64FC1, rotation, 2147483647); // works
        cvInitMatHeader(rotation_vector, 3, 3, CV_64FC1, rotation); // doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a specific example where that happens?

Comment: You could provide some code. VC++ works with default parameters just fine.

Comment: When typing in cvInitMatHeader(), intellisense gives you the parameter list.  It goes as follows: "(CvMat *mat, int rows, int cols, int type, void *data = (void*)0, int step = 2147483647)"

Comment: @soxarered: Well, I wanted you to find the actual declaration itself in the `cxcore.h` file itself. There might be some macros and intellisense may not show them.

Comment: @in silico: CVAPI(CvMat*) cvInitMatHeader( CvMat* mat, int rows, int cols,
                              int type, void* data CV_DEFAULT(NULL),
                              int step CV_DEFAULT(CV_AUTOSTEP) );

Comment: @soxarered: It may be possible that `CV_DEFAULT` expands into regular parameters and not default parameters. Can you find the definition of `CV_DEFAULT`?

Comment: @In silico:  Would this explain it working in g++ and not VS, though?  If that were the case, it shouldn't compile in either case.  Regardless, I will look for cv_default

Comment: @soxarered: I suspect it's because you're compiling in C mode and not C++ mode on VC++, so `CV_DEFAULT` expands into non-default parameters (they are not supported in C). [Check and see if VC++ is set to compile in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx).

Comment: @In silico: #define CV_DEFAULT(val) = val

Comment: @soxarered: Are there `#ifdef`/`#else`/`#endif` macros around it?

Comment: @In silico: Yes there are.  if _cplusplus is not defined, that is called.  Otherwise, #define CV_DEFAULT(val) is the statement, without the '= val'

Comment: @soxarered: Do you mean that if `__cplusplus` *is* defined, then the form with the equals sign is used? I think your VC++ project is set to compile C code and not C++ code, so `__cplusplus` ends up being undefined. [Check your project settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx).

Comment: @In silico: Yes, you're right.  I misread.  You are correct, too.  If you list this as an answer, I can accept.  Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration for `cvInitMatHeader()` is this:

```
CVAPI(CvMat*) cvInitMatHeader( CvMat* mat, int rows, int cols, int type,
    void* data CV_DEFAULT(NULL), int step CV_DEFAULT(CV_AUTOSTEP) );
```

The definition of `CV_DEFAULT` looks something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define CV_DEFAULT(val) = val
#else
    #define CV_DEFAULT(val)
#endif
```

So it appears that your Visual C++ compiler is actually compiling in C mode and not C++ mode. In C mode, `__cplusplus` would not be defined, so `CV_DEFAULT` expands to nothing. Therefore, it appears that the function declaration does not have default parameters.

[Check your project settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) and make sure you're compiling the code in C++ mode. That is, ensure that the `/Tp` or `/TP` compiler switch is enabled. You should also make sure your C++ files have the `.cpp` file extension.